# For iOS and Xcode, can we create an Action for a UIImageView object?

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder

It is easy that we create an Action for a `UIButton`, we just <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> drag the button on the canvas in Interface Builder to the `@implementation` part of our code (in the Assistant Editor).

But what about a `UIImageView`?  I want to say, if the user taps on this image (which is actually a good looking icon), then do something, but how can the Action be added because <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> drag doesn't do anything?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] 
                                     initWithTarget:self 
                                     action:@selector(actionHandleTapOnImageView)];
[singleTap setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
originalImageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[originalImageView addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
[singleTap release];




-(void)actionHandleTapOnImageView
{
NSLog(@"actionHandleTapOnImageView");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to handle the touchesBegan message in the UIImageView's parent UIViewController.

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {    
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    if ([touch view] == myImageView) {
        [self handleTapOnImageView];  // <-- Handle it!
    }
}
```

Also, make sure the UIImageView's "User Interaction Enabled" property is true.

Comment: oh I tried and view is the main view... that is, `[touch view]` is the view of the ViewController, not the UIImageView...

Comment: strange... I tried adding `UITapGestureRecognizer` to that UIImageView but it is not recognized either

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can actually use a UIButton and set its image just like you would for an UIImageView. No need for manually writing gesture handlers on an UIImageView.